# Import and Referencing the DLL Written By PowerBuilder into C#

Tags: c#, powerbuilder

I am a newbie programmer in C#.

Since there is one DLL which is programmed and complied by PowerBuilder and there is no source code left, I am trying to import this DLL file into C# for my owned interest.

The first thing that I have "Add Reference" thru the solution explorer.

However, I have googled a lot but there is a lot of supporting community for teaching to use C# DLL into PowerBuilder. I just have the API Specification when using this PowerBuilder DLL in PowerBuilder only.

So far I have no ideas to work on this. Any fruitful reply that I can be advised?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is a .net assembly, with a suitable license, and without dependencies on powerbuilder, it should be fairly simple to just import the dll by using "add Reference" and "Browse". To view the available classes you can double click on the reference to open it in the assembly explorer. Just listing available classes is a poor substitute for proper documentation, but better than nothing.

If these assumptions are wrong you can still use a decompiler like dotPeek to view a decompiled version of the source. Note that some licenses might not permit decompiling.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tried dotPeek but found it is "NOT SUPPORTED". I believed that is not written with PowerBuilder .NET assembly. Thanks anyway! 
PS: I can't vote as I am new to this forum. Sorry about that!